# Blackberry 10 Webworks with Worklight Geolocation

Tags: cordova, geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

I'm working with Worklight 6.1 and WebWorks SdK 2.1 for BlackBerry 10.

my issue is when I try to get the User location invoking this function :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    onSuccessGeo, onErrorGeo, {enableHighAccuracy: true});
```

I get this error :

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'e.code') geolocation.js:115

Though when I run a sample project based on Webworks SDK 2.1, with cordova, the geolocation works fine.

I made the same configuration and permissions for the 2 projects, both with Worklight and without Worklight.

Did I miss something?

Comment: To clarify, if you build a pure Cordova app, it works, but with Worklight, it doesn't work? What version of Cordova did you test with?

Comment: yes that's it, I'm using Cordova 3.5.0 the one by default for Webworks SDK 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by replacing Geolocation plugin of Worklight by the one generated by Webworks SDK 2.1.

So you have to copy the Geolocation Plugin under :

```
ProjectFolder/plugin/org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

and past it under :

```
/ProjectFolder/webresources/default/worklight/plugins/org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

[image]

------->

[image]

That's all, hope it will help you if you'll face such problem.