# Blackberry10 doesn't show the Worklight plugins folder

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

When I build the blackberry environment, I'm able to generate the native folder using ANT scripts. However, I don't see the Worklight plugins folder inside the

```
/native/www/webresources/default/worklight
```

[image]

During the ANT build, I see that I'm pointing to the correct sdks path:

```
[app-builder] WARNING: FWLST1123I: Using BlackBerry WEBWORKS_HOME path: /Applications/BB10 WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15
```

In ANT script I'm using:

```
<target name="build-wl-app-src">
    <echo level="info">IMP: Build Worklight Project for ${wl.server.SRC}</echo>

    <echo level="info"> - Building Worklight artifacts and creating native project source for  iPhone and Android, common, blackberry10</echo>
    <app-builder applicationFolder="${wl.project.location.SRC}/apps/${wl.application.name}" environments="android,iphone,ipad,common,blackberry10" outputfolder="${output.location.SRC}" worklightserverhost="${wl.server.SRC}" nativeprojectprefix="${project.name}"/>
</target>
```

any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: You're also using WebWorks SDK 2.2... what is your Worklight version? Make sure you are up-to-date: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/03/05/ootb-support-blackberry-webworks-2-2/

Comment: Worklight version 6.2.0.01, is my Webworks SDK is out of date. I have downloaded the latest one from the BB developers website.?

Comment: Im not saying it's out of date. For bb10 you must use the latest ifix (and the ant jar from its server installation folder) which contains built in support for webworks 2.2 per the blog post I've linked you to.

Comment: I get now, how can we get the latest ifix? do we need to raise a request for it.?

Comment: No. You go to Fix Central and download it.

Comment: Thank you, would you please give me the fix ID or any information that can help me getting it. Appreciate your response

Comment: The latest, ifix, from fix central. Latest. Newest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when using Studio, the path you've mentioned does not show a "plugins" folder, and I believe this is OK.

Starting WebWorks 2.x the project structure of a BlackBerry 10 project has changed dramatically from what you're used to with WebWorks 1.x.

If you WEBWORKS_HOME environment variable is pointing to the WebWorks 2.x SDK then Studio (and the Ant builder .jar file) will generate the new project structure.

You will find the plugins folder here: native\plugins

This is mentioned in the blog post from the comments: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/03/05/ootb-support-blackberry-webworks-2-2/

If you need to migrate from WebWorks 1.x to 2.x, there's a quick guide here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/setting-up-your-development-environment/setting-blackberry-10-development-environment/

Comment: The reason I need the plugin folder inside the worklight is because of this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951511/blackberry-10-webworks-with-worklight-geolocation). I was doing the build through windows machine "eclipse studio" and there is a "plugin" folder generated during the build. but now I moved to Mac OS using Ant builder and I don't see it. we have downloaded the latest ifix provided by IBM which contains the "iPhone6+ splash screen resolution issue". So I'm almost sure I have the latest fix which is released on March. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is not the same. Things have changed. Use the plugins folder I have mentioned...